# Need to include the default column when i do group by with unstack option from count() aggregation

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

data_group = data.groupby(['date','env'])['date'].count().unstack().fillna(0)
I am getting the something like this.. But when i query by filterData.iloc[:,-1].. It returns column1.. How to get or include the date column in this dataframe

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) you can use **reset_index** method to have the index as a column. This has to be put after the **fillna**:

```
data_group = data.groupby(['date','env'])['date'].count().unstack().fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Its new name of the column will be **index** and tou need to rename it, if you do not want that name. To do so you can you the [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html?highlight=rename#pandas.DataFrame.rename) method.